# Bash- How to check if file is empty in a loop

Tags: bash, shell

I need to check in Bash file is empty,

if it's empty keep tracking him until something is written to it.

In case something was written to it echo it to the screen and stop checking the file content.

```
for [ -s diff.txt ]; do
echo "file is empty - keep checking it "
done
echo "file is not empty "
cat  diff.txt
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just use a `while`?

```
while ! [ -s diff.txt ]; do
    echo "file is empty - keep checking it "
    sleep 1 # throttle the check
done
echo "file is not empty "
cat  diff.txt
```

The loop will run as long as `! [ -s diff.txt ]` is true. If you prefer, you can use `until` instead of `while` and remove the negation (`!`).

Comment: Note : '-s' is for testing if a file is not zero size.